# Select order by... cant' find error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem, trying to sort my Select request -

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`  OREDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 10 ;
```

I get error #1064:

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'BY `score` DESC LIMIT 10' at line 1

But I realy don't know wats wrong ! Names and quotes are right, as I think... as this request works correctly:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`uid`, `score`) VALUES ("'.$viewer_id.'","'.$uscore.'") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `score` = "'.$uscore.'";';
```

Can somebody help me!!??

P.S sorry for my English(

Answer (score 2):

it's `ORDER` not `OREDER`

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10
```

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You have a spelling error in your syntax it's 'ORDER BY' not 'OREDER BY' the correct syntax should be:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`  ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 10 ;
```